# Python3: Split+concatenate string with regex - giving syntax error: can't assign to operator

Tags: python, regex, syntax-error

I am attempting to use a regex to split and concatenate a string but am getting an error message... as I can't see the problem, I am a little lost as to what to do.

code:

```
import re
s = 'Defect centre is at   0.0000   0.0000   0.2984  Frac'
M-L_centre = ' '.join(re.finditer('[\d.]+', s))
```

gives:

> SyntaxError: can't assign to operator

the intended result would be:

```
M-L_centre = '0.0000 0.0000 0.2984'
```

Comment: @pratZ not needed to escape `.` inside the [...]

Comment: I scanned through the 2.7 Python Doc [regex page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). I can't seem to find a `re.iter()`, only a `re.finditer()`

Comment: @skamazin my error there - not reading the HOW TO page properly... question updated to reflect this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`M-L_centre` has a hyphen in it, and so it's an arithmetic expression rather than a variable (or whatever you intended), and so you can't assign to it.